# How is my android security camera app accessing my internal home network externally?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I installed a SWANN home security camera system and installed it on my network. Somehow, I can access my cameras on my home internal network via the SWANN Android app. However, I did not provide anything to the app other than "logging into my SWANN account". Likewise, this is also with other home devices like "Wink Hub". Given I have not specifically opened a port or setup a Dynamic DNS service, how is this happening? Is there some "service" that is running internal to my network that opened a port and is providing my WAN IP back to "their" (e.g. SWANN or Wink) servers that allow me access?

Answer (score 1):

Your camera uses P2P protocol to transfer data to the client which doesn't need any static IP address, DDNS configuration and port forwarding.As you could read [here](http://www.karassnsecurity.com/news/what-is-a-p2p-ip-camera-and-how-does-it-work-178733.html):

> P2P stands for "Peer to Peer". It is a technology that makes it simple
>   to link the camera with a smartphone.
>
> In camera speak, there is a UID (unique ID) assigned to each camera.
>   When the smartphone app is opened, it pings the P2P server which in
>   turn looks for the listed UIDs and where they are located. If the
>   camera can be pinged, it shows as online, others are offline.
>
> Once the cameras are reached, it creates a direct connection between
>   the app and the camera. Just like the popular Bittorent peer to peer
>   file sharing platform.

Comment: Thanks harsini; however, when you say "If the camera can be pinged", ...I don't understand how the P2P server can "ping" my camera as it is inside my firewall and local network.  That is what I don't understand.  Any further clarification you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: I am not familiar with the protocol mechanism but I guess camera itself report its availability status to the manufacture server's.